# ElasticsearchClient not returning results properly with lambda query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I recently upgraded my elasticsearch version to 7.16 and i found out that RestHighLevelClient is deprecated now so I'm trying to migrate to ElasticsearchClient with it's lambda query but I have a problem when proper query results are 0

I create client like this:

```
private ElasticsearchClient createClient() {
    // Create the low-level client
    RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost(ServerStatic.SERVER_URL, ServerStatic.ELASTIC_PORT)).build();

    // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
    ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
            restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

    // And create the API client
    ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
    return client;
}
```

Then i create my query

```
ElasticsearchClient client = createClient();
    
        List<TitleBasic> found = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
                SearchResponse<TitleBasic> search = client.search(
                    s -> s.index(ServerStatic.ELASTIC_INDEX)
                          .size(20)
                          .from(0)
                          .query(q -> q.bool(
                                  b -> b.must(
                                     m -> m.queryString(
                                            qs -> qs.allowLeadingWildcard(true)
                                                    .query(phrase + "*")          
                                                    .fields("originalTitle"))))),
                        TitleBasic.class);
                found = search.documents();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
```

And it should fetch 6 documents as my query send from postman does

```
POST {{es_url}}/test-index/_search

{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
                        "query":"Carmencita*",
                        "fields": ["originalTitle"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0
}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, anyone have any ideas what's wrong with that lambda query?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that query was working properly but parsing was bad.

I shouldn't have used search.documents for result list, instead of that I should use

```
for (Hit<TitleBasic> hit: search.hits().hits()) {
    TitleBasic item = hit.source();
    found.add(item);
}
```